# The maxPriority setting don't work in spring-cloud-stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm building a spring-cloud application and using stream to manage my rabbitmq priority queue. But the `maxPriority` settings in the application.yml don't work.

Here's my configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          highLevelOutput:
            producer:
              maxPriority: 10
          highLevelInput:
            consumer:
              maxPriority: 10
      bindings:
        highLevelOutput:
          destination: notification-high
          contentType: application/x-java-object;type=com.txn.notification.entity.NotificationMessage
        highLevelInput:
          group: high
          producer:
            requiredGroups: high
          destination: notification-high
          contentType: application/x-java-object;type=com.txn.notification.entity.NotificationMessage
          contentType: application/x-java-object;type=com.txn.notification.entity.NotificationMessage
```

And I noticed that in the stream's RabbitConsumerProperties class there's nothing related to the priority configuration, is this property read from anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it worked fine for me...

[image: Priority Queue]

Note that the queue must not already exist - you can't change the max priority of an existing queue. It will be ignored in that case.

What version are you using? The property is in `RabbitCommonProperties` the super class of `RabbitConsumerProperties`.

It only applies to the producer if it has required groups, since it's a queue property and producers don't deal with queues directly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,It works after i update all the pom dependency,really appreciate it bro!